# Remove duplicates by group and column within that group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to remove duplicates in each group, seems pretty straight forward by I am having problems dealing with group series. Considering this data:

```
import pandas as pd


data = {
  'Keyword': ['car', 'car', 'car', 'bus', 'bus','bus'], 
  'Colour': ['blue','blue','red','blue','yellow','yellow']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

print(df)
```

I get this output

```
  Keyword  Colour
0     car    blue
1     car    blue
2     car     red
3     bus    blue
4     bus  yellow
5     bus  yellow
```

I am trying to get

```
  Keyword  Colour
0     car    blue
1     car     red
2     bus    blue
3     bus  yellow
```

I have tried this but is not working on series

```
test = df.groupby(['Keyword', 'Colour']).size().drop_duplicates('Colour', keep='first')
```

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(['Keyword','Colour'])`?

Comment: @QuangHoang, I cannot believe it was this simple, thank you very much